# htaccess to redirect url's that contain something

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, parameters

I am trying to find out how to do something like this in htaccess:

```
#This address links to a place that does not exist
localhost/prefix/games/userid/game-name
```

to silently ([L], i guess) redirect to

```
#This folder has an index.php, so we're good!
localhost/prefix/protected/files/userid/game-name/
```

I realise I can have a link:

```
localhost/prefix/games/index.php?user=userid&title=game-name
```

And just have the index.php have some redirect put in...

**But I don't want the url paramaters visible in a link on my website**... So I guess it really does need to be htaccess.

I've got to admit, I read that htaccess stuff and it goes right past my head because noone has explained in a way I understand.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT::///

```
RewriteEngine On        
RewriteBase /prefix

# stop directory listings
Options -Indexes 

#stops htaccess views
<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>

# remove .php; use THE_REQUEST to prevent infinite loops
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ (.*)\.php\ HTTP
    RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ $1 [R=301]         

# remove index
    RewriteRule (.*)/index$ $1/ [R=301]

# remove slash if not directory
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
    RewriteRule (.*)/ $1 [R=301]

# add .php to access file, but don't redirect
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
    RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]    

# redirect game folders
    RewriteRule ^prefix/games/(.*)$ /prefix/protected/files/$1/ [R=301]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have

```
RewriteRule ^prefix/games/(.*)$ prefix/protected/files/$1 [L]
```

to redirect all **`http://localhost/prefix/games/userid/game-name`** links to **`http://localhost/prefix/protected/files/userid/game-name`**

or, you can have

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} user=(.*)&title=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^prefix/games/index.php$ /prefix/protected/files/%1/%2? [L]
```

to move all links like: **`http://localhost/prefix/games/index.php?user=userid&title=game-name`** to **`http://localhost/prefix/protected/files/userid/game-name`**

Comment: Looking at the first one:

^ = host/domain, (.*) = store this part in a variable, $1 call the variable set?

Comment: `^` => starting just after domain and remaining two assumptions are correct.

Comment: You good sir, are very helpful. I shall try doubly to do the next one myself. TICK!

Comment: If I were to change RewriteRule ^prefix/games/(.*)$ prefix/protected/files/$1 [L] to [R=301] should the url be rewritten to http://localhost/prefix/protected/files/userid/game-name. Or do I then need a RewriteCond. Can you give me an example?

Comment: yes it should. I've myself never used `[R]` rule much. You can check your rewrite rules here: [htaccess madewithlove](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/)

Comment: Omg, that's amazing. Thankyou, that's going to help a LOT!

Comment: Last question. Is there any reason why it may not work on my localhost (WAMP). the htaccess is running because previous rules work. If I test my whole htaccess file in the tester, it does what I want it to do. But when I run on my localhost, it doesn't. Any ideas? It's simply not doing anything. I've included my whole file in original text.

Comment: @JamesT That is happening because of the ordering of your rules. move the rule above this condition: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10307943/problems-with-htaccess-redirect

ill tick this one as answered.. can u help me out.. and im guessing that is waht ive done