# Problems with htaccess redirect

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

On the following site: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

fill the request url with: http://localhost/prefix/games/u_id/game-name

Put this in the htaccess area:

```
RewriteEngine On        
RewriteBase /prefix

# stop directory listings
Options -Indexes 

#stops htaccess views
<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>        

# redirect game folders     
    RewriteRule ^prefix/games/(.*)$ prefix/protected/files/$1 [L]

# remove .php; use THE_REQUEST to prevent infinite loops
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ (.*)\.php\ HTTP
    RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ $1 [R=301]     

# remove index
    RewriteRule (.*)/index$ $1/ [R=301]

# remove slash if not directory
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
    RewriteRule (.*)/ $1 [R=301]

# add .php to access file, but don't redirect
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
    RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]       

ErrorDocument 404 /prefix/error-404.php
```

The result comes out as: http://localhost/prefix/protected/files/u_id/game-name

Now if I put that htaccess file on my wamp localhost server and goto the same url as we put in the request url on that site. it returns 404 page not found... and yet if i visit the result page from the test site (the one above), it loads the index.php page that is there.

The redirect is not working for my localhost website. Any ideas? the htaccess file is definitely running.

EDIT::///

My Apache access log is outputting:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Apr/2012:18:44:02 +0100] "GET /prefix/games/u_id/game-name HTTP/1.1" 404 116
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Apr/2012:18:44:02 +0100] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 209
```

**EDIT::///**

SOLVEd.

Comment: Can I clarify my question at all? I still am hopelessly lost with this issue.

Comment: `RewriteBase /prefix` can be correct if your htaccess in inside the root directory. If the htaccess is inside the prefix directory, your rewriterules should not start with prefix. Where is the htaccess located?

Comment: The htaccess if in the root directory called 'prefix':

http://localhost/prefix/.htaccess

Comment: OMFg.. I LOVE YOU. I just realised what you said.. YOU ARE A LEGENDDDD.. AGHHH I LOVE YOU.. thankyou *cries* thankyou.. 2 DAYS OF HELL MAN.. OMFG I LOVE U.

Comment: Just mark my solution as the answer, and we'll call it even ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RewriteBase /prefix` can't be correct if your htaccess in inside the root directory. If the htaccess is inside the prefix directory, your rewriterules should not start with prefix. Where is the htaccess located?